# Find unitary operator and measure

Tags: functional-analysis

I have following problem. Let $A$ be a linear self-adjoint operator in a finite-dimensional space. Find a unitary operator $U$, a measure $μ$, and a function $a$ such that $UAU^{−1} = B$, where $B \in B(L_2([0,1],μ))$, $(Bx)(t)= a(t)x( t)$.
My attempt was the next:
Let the operator $A$ act in a finite-dimensional Euclidean space $E$ of dimension $2$. Let $\left\{ λ_j \right\}^n_{j = 1}$ be the eigenvalues ​​of the operator $A$, numbered in an arbitrary order with multiplicity taken into account, and $\left\{e_j \right\}^n_{j=1}$ are the corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors. Lets choose arbitrary $n$ points $\left\{t_j\right\}^n_{j=1}$ on the segment $[0,1]$, for example, $t_j = \frac{j}{(n+1)}$, and set $μ = \sum_{j = 1}^nδ_j$, where $δ_j$ is the point measure concentrated at the point $t_j$, i.e., $δ_j(A) = 1$ if $t_j ∈ A$, $0$ otherwise, for any set $A⊂[0,1]$. Lets define the operator $U$ according to the rule $U: x → \sum^n_{j=1} f_jχ_j(t)$, where $χ_j = 1$ if $t = t_j$, $0$ otherwise, and $f_j = (x,e_j)$ is the coefficient in the expansion of the vector $x$ in terms of basis $\left\{e_j\right\}^n_1$.
But here i have a problem to calcuate $UAU^{-1}$ and find function $a(t)$, could somebody help me? Thank you!